# Retrieving and editting location information associated with photos

Tags: facebook, geolocation, location, photo

I need to be able to retrieve Facebook Places associated with a user's photos, and hopefully also link photos to Places. I'm referring to the way you can use the "Add Location" functionality to choose a Place while looking at a photo. I haven't been able to locate where this link is kept either through fql or open graph calls.

- There is no Place information in the [Photo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object.
- An [Album](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) can have a 'location', but this is only a string, not a Place, and not specific to a photo.
- Places can be associated with Posts or Checkins, but as far as I can tell a Photo isn't necessary associated with either of these.

Hope some one can help!

Brendan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with the public Graph API to do what you want. You can contact Facebook to see if the functionality exists on their API they have for white-listed apps.

This is an answer not a comment.

The answer is that it is impossible to do that with the public API.  You can check with Facebook to see if it's possible to become a partner or get your app white listed to get that functionality.

Comment: Yeah, some moderator was changing my answer into a comment.  Twice the did it in one day on two separate questions.  :|  I don't know why....